# Can CNN learn to weigh certain feature channels much, much more than others?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent

This is a hypothetical question.

**Assumptions**

- I am working on a 2 class semantic segmentation task
- My ground truths are binary masks
- batch size is 1
- at an arbitrary point in my network there is a convolution layer called `'conv_5'` which has a feature map size of 90 x 45 x 512.

Let's assume I also decide that (during training) I will concatenate the ground truth mask to `'conv_5'`. This will result in a new top we can call `'concat_1'` which will be a 90 x 45 x 513 dimension feature map.

Assume that the rest of the network follows a normal pattern like a few more convolution layers, a fully connected, and softmax loss.

**My question is, can the fully connected layers learn to weigh the first 512 feature channels very low and weigh the last feature channel (which we know is a perfect ground truth) very high?**

If this is true then is it true in principle such that if the feature dimension was 1,000,000 channels and I add the last channel as the perfect ground truth it will still learn to effectively ignore all previous 1,000,000 feature channels?

My intuition is that if there is ever a VERY good feature channel passed in then a network should be able to learn to utilize this channel far more than the others. I would also like to think that this is independent to the number of channels.

(In practice I have a scenario where I am passing in a nearly perfect ground truth as the 513th feature map, but it seems to have no impact at all. Then when I examine the magnitudes of the weights across all 513 feature channels, the magnitudes are roughly the same across all channels. This leads me to believe that the "nearly perfect mask" is only being utilized about 1/513th of it's potential. This is what has motivated me to ask the question.)

Answer (score 2):

Hypothetically, if you have a "killing feature" in your disposal, the net should learn to use it and ignore the "noise" from the rest of the features.

BTW, Why are you using a fully connected layer for semantic segmentation? I'm not sure this is "a normal pattern" for semantic segmentation nets.

**What may prevent the net from identifying the "killing features"?**
 - The layers above `"conv_5"` mess things up: if they reduce resolution (sampling/pooling/striding...) then information is lost, and it is difficult to utilize the information. Specifically, I suspect the fully-connected layer that might globally mess things up.
 - A bug: the way you add the "killing feature" is not aligned with the image. Either the mask is added transposed, or you erroneously add the mask of one image to another (do you "shuffle" the training samples?)

**An interesting experiment:**
You can check if the net has at least a locally optimal weights that uses the "killing features": you can use [net surgery](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb) to manually set the weights such that `"conv_5"` is zero for all features but the "killing features" and the weights for the consequent layers are not messing this up. Then you should have very high accuracy and low loss. Training the net from this point should yield very small (if any) gradients and the weights should not change significantly even after many iterations.

Comment: Thank you Shai for the quick answer! I was incorrect in mentioning that there is a fully connected layer. There was one in the network previously for other reasons for a multi-task training. It isn't there anymore.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to do net surgery and set the weights to zero to help make sure that nothing funny has happened to the masks and that it can indeed achieve high accuracy and low loss as we would expect. I do think something odd is happening in my case.